# margin:auto not working in ie5

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-5

Using IE11's developer tools you can change the browser mode. Everything looks fine in Edge, 10, 9, 8 and 7, however IE5 forces the `div` to be aligned to the left rather than the middle.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: typical IE problem, I don't think you need to support IE5 anymore, but please post your code for us the help you.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to support IE5? Who uses that anymore?

Comment: if 6% of humanity are using ie6, then people must be using ie5.

Comment: @ben — That doesn't mean they need to get a pretty version of your website. (It does mean that their systems are probably infected with so much malware that they are unusable though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IE 5 predates Microsoft's support for auto margins](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#ie).

You can hack it by (exploiting a bug in old-IE and) setting `text-align: center` on the *parent* element and then `text-align: left` on the element you want centred.

That said, IE5 is very old, completely unsupported by Microsoft and with a market share as close to zero as makes no difference for almost everyone. I wouldn't try supporting it at all.